# Recursion in lambda in Elisp

Tags: emacs, recursion, lambda, elisp

I have the following Python code:

```
def sum_fibonacci():
    '''Project Euler: 2
    Sum of even-valued terms of Fibonacci sequence < 4 mil
    '''
    def i(a, b, acc):
        if a >= 4000000: return acc
        if a % 2 == 0:
            return i(a + b, a, acc + a)
        else: return i(a + b, a, acc)
    return i(2, 1, 0)
```

I want to translate it to Emacs Lisp. In [Higher-order functions in Elisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12772510/596361) i was told not to use `defun` within `defun`, because it enables the function globally, so i wrote lambda instead. But i need to make lambda call itself recursively.

My code is:

```
(defun sum-fibonacci ()
  (let ((i
         (lambda (a b acc)
           (cond ((>= a 4000000) acc)
                 ((evenp a) (funcall i (+ a b) a (+ a acc)))
                 (t (funcall i (+ a b) a acc))))))
    (funcall i 2 1 0)))
```

However the function `i` is called before it is assigned with `let`, and i get an error - `*** Eval error ***  Symbol's value as variable is void: i`

**How do i do recursion in lambda in Elisp?**

Comment: You might also want to discover `flet`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [Recursing in a lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7607338/596361) I rewrote it with `labels`:

```
(defun sum-fibonacci ()
  (labels ((i (a b acc)
              (cond ((>= a 4000000) acc)
                    ((evenp a) (i (+ a b) a (+ a acc)))
                    (t (i (+ a b) a acc)))))
    (i 2 1 0)))
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can do this in emacs lisp.

```
(funcall (lambda (fib a b acc) (funcall fib a b acc fib)) ;;lambda1
         (lambda (a b acc fib)                            ;;lambda2
           (cond ((>= a 40000) acc)
                 ((zerop (mod a 2)) (funcall fib (+ a b) a (+ acc a) fib))
                 (t (funcall fib (+ a b) a acc fib))))
         2 1 0)
```

The main idea is using a helper lambda (`lambda1`) to call the real lambda (`lambda2`) and pass the real lambda (`lambda2`) to itself.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the commas in the lambda list:

```
(defun sum-fibonacci ()
  (labels ((rec (a b acc)
                (cond ((>= a 4000000) acc)
                      ((evenp a) (rec (+ a b) a (+ a acc)))
                      (t (rec (+ a b) a acc)))))
    (rec 2 1 0)))
```